# How to zoom android camera more than actually provided, especially front facing camera?

Tags: android, camera, zooming, front-camera

I would like to implement android camera zoom by loosing quality. So I want to achieve result to zoom more than provided or allowed in built in camera. The same thing I want to do also for rear camera. Are there ideas?

p.s. I know how it works setZoom by camera parameters. but it gives to me maxZoom = 30, actually 4x zoom. I need more.